# LDAP + Keycloak forces password change

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openldap

I am currently setting up my LDAP (OpenLDAP) and connecting it with my Keycloak. However, when I try to log into an account created via LDAP on Keycloak, I get the error "resolve_required_actions" because it seems that I have required actions open.

I tried resolving it by deleting the required action from the user but when I save the user it just comes back. I looked into the configuration of the identity provider, I also disabled the action in Keycloak. No success.

Could someone please explain me how to get rid of that action? And also (if possible) why this problem appears in the first place since I haven't found anything relatable in my research. This is my first getting to know LDAP (and it's a little confusing for me in combination with Keycloak) so I am very thankful for all information you can give me!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately I remember that I had to setup a new Keycloak using Postgres as the database. The error then went away.